# What's the most efficient way to have a back button go to the previous listview from the current?

Tags: java, android, performance, listview

I have a series of `listview`'s that categorise different things.

For example, the `listview` reads Colors and Shapes, when the user clicks Colors, it brings up another listview that has colors in the list, if they click shapes, a list of shapes shows up. All that is fine until the user needs to go back a view, that's where I have nothing... well, nothing efficient. The only thing I could think of was to have a whole bunch of confusing switch statements. How should I do this?

Comment: See if you can adapt [this idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40052574/how-can-i-do-a-return-back-button-in-java/40054491#40054491).

Comment: How did you implement that transition between different lists?Do you use fragments for that?Show us some code.